# asynchronous function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

It's just a little question about asynchronous function in nodejs and the good way to create them. the following takes in parameters a repository and an extension name and return the list of the files with the given extension in the given repository

to run

```
$ node app /path/to/some/reposity someExtension
```

module.js file

```
//modules.js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
module.exports = function(dir, ext, callback){
    //do something
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            //EDIT
            process.nexTick(function(){
                callback(err);
            });
            //
        }
        if(data){
            var compteur = 0;
            var block = [];
            for(var i =0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
                if(path.extname(data[i]).slice(1) == ext){
                    block[compteur]= data[i];
                    compteur++;
                }
            }
            //EDIT
            process.nextTick(function(){
                callback(null, block);
            });
            //
        }

    });
};
```

app.js file

```
//app.js
var dir = process.argv[2];
var ext = process.argv[3];
var module = require('./module');

module(dir, ext, function(err, data){
    if(err) { throw err;}
    var dl = data.length;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < dl ; i++){
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
});
```

I just wanted to know if it's the good way to do things or if there a better one. Thanks in advance.

I find this nice tutorial on asynchronous function in NodeJS
http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick

Comment: That's a pretty standard approach, though you should be aware that the `return` statements before the `callback()` calls aren't really doing anything useful.

Comment: ...and you have an extra closing parenthesis `function(err, data))` <--

Comment: @BlueSkies if this approach is standard is there any other way to get the same result? For the return statements, I saw callback with and without them, I preferred let them for the moment.

Comment: doing `return callback(..)` is a good habit as you might go have a bug where the `callback(..)` is called twice !

Comment: thanks, I just start nodejs few days ago, and had some problem understanding this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to program asynchronously is to use callbacks, which is what you've doing. Since the callback is nested within an asynchronous function, it will be queued once the callstack is empty.

Also, don't name any variables [`module`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_module). It is a global variable which should not be overwritten.

Comment: thanks, is it better to emit events instead of sending callback or is it similar?

Comment: The use case depends on what you're doing. Sometimes one or the either is more convenient to use.

Comment: I actually failed to notice that. Thanks for pointing that out. That being said, I shall stop answering questions while lacking sleep.